# web-app authentication with users from any domains

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, adfs, acs, thinktecture-ident-server

Which authentication mechanism should i go with if i want my web-app to support users with following IP's and provide a single-signon experience with other linked web-apps
1. Google 
2. Microsoft
3. Facebook
4. ArbitaryDomain1
5. ArbitaryDomain1

I have been reading a lot and came across following
1. Using ThinkTecture as a ID store(Google,Microsoft,Facebook) and creating ADFS(ArbitaryDomain1,ArbitaryDomain2), here my web-app can communicate with ADFS that wraps Thinktecture and other arbitarydomains (NOT Sure how)...Pls suggest
2. Using OpenID Connect
3. Using ACS

But can finalize on any one and is open with any valid suggestions.
Please share your valueable comments.

Answer (score 0):

What repository are you using? AD? SQL DB?

If AD, use ADFS.

If SQL DB, use Thinktecture.

The social logins can be done with ADFS / Thinktecture federated with ACS.

Is your ArbitaryDomain .NET based? If so use WIF against ADFS / Thinktecture?